# How to check if Insert Mode is enabled for TextBox in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, insertion

I have a custom inheritor of `Behavior<TextBox>` and I would like to correctly handle `PreviewTextInput` and `Pasting` events to filter input data but I can't process input data when Insert Mode is enabled. I check if Insert Mode is on using `Keyboard.IsKeyToggled(Key.Insert)`, but every `TextBox` has its own state for Insert Mode.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share the full behavior and usage code?

Comment: @meilke It doesn't matter. The problem is that it seems there are no straight way to check Insert Mode without using own flags and handling all key events for every TextBox.